# Simple upper bound for $t(2\Phi(\alpha/t) - 1)$, where $\alpha > 0$ and $t \in (0, 1)$

Tags: real-analysis, upper-lower-bounds, symbolic-computation, distribution-tails, gaussian

Let $\alpha > 0$ and $ t \in (0, 1)$. For simplicity, take $\alpha=1$. Let $\Phi$ be the normal cumulative distribution function.

Of course, the core of the problem is the term $t\Phi(\alpha/t)$. Note that this function is nondecreasing.

> **Question.** Is there an obvious simple upper bound for
>   $t(2\Phi(\alpha/t)-1)$ ?

**Important note.** By "simple", I mean things things like simple polynomials, exponentials (e.g $C_1e^{-C_2t^2}$), but not things like exponential divided by polynomial, etc., which would be obtained, for example using Wilk's ratio.

This leads me to my second question

> **Question.** Is it possible to use symbolic computing tools like wolframalpha to solve such problems ? If **yes**, how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$t \left(2 \Phi \left(\frac{\alpha }{t}\right)-1\right)=t\, \text{erf}\left(\frac{\alpha }{t\sqrt{2} }\right)$$
and we know that
$$\text{erf}(x) \leq \sqrt{1-e^{-\frac{4 }{\pi }x^2}}$$ making
$$t\, \text{erf}\left(\frac{\alpha }{t\sqrt{2} }\right)\leq t\, \sqrt{1-e^{-\frac{2 \alpha ^2}{\pi  t^2}}}$$